Is there any AND condition in MIPS that can check two conditions at the same time?
I made a code in MIPS where a student enters assesment grade,midterm grade , final exam grade. When i run the program it asks the user for input of the 3 grades and then my program is supposed to check if my final exam grade and my final grade is both above 5 then jump to pass message otherwise even if final grade is above 5 but final exam grade is below 5 then jump to fail.
.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Assessment grade: \n"
prompt2: .asciiz "Midterm grade: \n"
prompt3: .asciiz "Final exam grade: \n"
final_grade_msg: .asciiz "Your final grade is: "
pass_msg: .asciiz "You have passed. \n"
fail_msg: .asciiz "You have failed, try again next year \n"
continue_msg: .asciiz "Do you want to continue? (y/n):  \n"
terminate_msg: .asciiz "Program terminated. \n"
newline: .asciiz "\n"

.text
.globl main

main:
    li $t3, 20   # Assessment mark (20%)
    li $t4, 30   # Midterm mark (30%)
    li $t5, 50   # Final exam mark (50%)

loop:
    # Print newline
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall

    # Input assessment grade
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt1
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t0, $v0

    # Input midterm grade
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt2
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t1, $v0

    # Input final exam grade
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt3
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t2, $v0

    # Calculate weighted grades
    mul $t0, $t0, $t3  # t0 = t0 * 20%
    mul $t1, $t1, $t4  # t1 = t1 * 30%
    mul $t2, $t2, $t5  # t2 = t2 * 50%

    # Sum up the grades: t6 = t0 + t1 + t2
    add $t6, $t0, $t1  # t6 = t0 + t1
    add $t6, $t6, $t2  # t6 = t6 + t2

    # Calculate final grade (percentage)
    div $t6, $t6, 100
    mflo $t7  # Store quotient in $t7

    # Print final grade
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, final_grade_msg
    syscall
    li $v0, 1          # syscall code for printing an integer
    move $a0, $t7      # load the final grade into $a0
    syscall

    # Print newline
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall

    # Check if both final grade and final exam grade are above 5
    li $t9, 50
    
    bge $t2, $t9, pass
    bge $t7, 5, pass
    j fail

pass:
    # Code for passing the student
    # Printing pass message
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, pass_msg
    syscall
    j continue

fail:
    # Code for failing the student
    # Printing fail message
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, fail_msg
    syscall
    j continue

continue:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, continue_msg
    syscall

    li $v0, 12
    syscall
    beq $v0, 121, loop
    j terminate

terminate:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, terminate_msg
    syscall

    li $v0, 10
    syscall

I tried using bge (be greater than or equal to) to check whether whether the grades are above 5 but for some reason i feel like if the first condition is true it skips the next one.
This is my output
This is my output:
Assesment grade: 
10
Midterm grade: 
10 
Final exam grade:
1
Your final grade is:5 
You have passed. 
Do you want to continue?y/n 


In assembly language, you need to build complex conditions out of simpler ones. MIPS does not know how to check two conditions at once. (If the first condition is true, then it skips the next one because you told it to skip! bge $t2, $t9, pass: If $t2 is greater than or equal to $t9, then skip to pass.)

@RaymondChen how should i approach the conditions properly?

Does this answer your question? MIPS assembly: instruction "beq" and the 'and' operator

Try a very small program.  It can be in assembly or in C using if-goto.  When you have your logic working, you xan fix your assembly code.
